# Как работать с TCP в Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tcp-ip

У меня есть `TCP` сервер, который слушает входящие команды и общается с БД. Как мне слать к нему запросы из `ios` приложения? Работаю со `swift 2`.

Другими словами, нужно реализовать следующее:
Пользователь вводит логин и пароль, пытается войти в свой аккаунт. В это время посылается запрос на сервер - "Проверь, есть ли такой юзер в БД". Он это делает, и шлет ответ обратно на `ios` приложение.

Никак не могу понять, как мне такое реализовать. Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно работать с потоками, но ничего путного про это на `ios` я не нашел.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003063/ios-simple-tcp-connection-example мб тут что-нибудь полезное в ответах есть?

Comment: Да, я смотрел эту тему. Увы там дан пример на Objective-C, что мне не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то потоки Вам вовсе не нужны. Тут надо использовать блоки. Скажем Вы отправляете запрос и включаете индикатор загрузки, а когда приходит ответ Вы прекращаете загрузку и в зависимости от результата с сервера используете `success` или же `failure` блок. Советую использовать [AFNetworking](http://www.davidebettio.com/use-afnetworking-with-swift/).

Что-то на подобии

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()  
manager.GET(  
  "http://myServerUrl.com",
  parameters: ["email":"myemail@gmail.com", "password":"1234Password"],
  success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
              responseObject: AnyObject!) in
     //TODO - make login action
  },
  failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
              error: NSError!) in
      // TODO - show error message
  }
)
```

Comment: У меня `TCP` сервер, то есть он ждет, пока к нему подключится `TCPClient`, и они начинают общаться друг с другом через поток. Так у меня реализовано клиент-серверное приложение на `C#`. И вот я хочу, чтобы `ios` приложение так же подключалось к серверу, и так же общалось с ним посредством потока. Это возможно? Я не понимаю, как можно слать `GET/POST` запросы к моему серверу, ведь у меня нет его URL - у меня есть его IP и номер Порта.

Comment: @AndreyMorozov получается что у вас общение через сокеты?

Comment: Получается, что да. Могу прикрепить основной кусочек кода сервера, если нужно.

Comment: Тогда Вам необходимо работать с сокетами. Смотрите тут: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift или же https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket. А так же хорошая статья: http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/

Comment: Да, видел эти библиотеки. Уже мыкаюсь с ними третий день, и никак не получается достичь желаемого. Вы сами работали с ними?

Comment: К сожалению на Swift c сокетами не работал, только в Objective-C.

Comment: @AndreyMorozov может эта ссылка Вам поможет http://swiftrien.blogspot.com.ee/2015/10/socket-programming-in-swift-part-1.html

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю вам необходимо выполнить HTTP запрос авторизации пользователя к вашему серверу и получить какой то ответ. Для работы с сетью на Swift вам подойдет [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

Самый простой пример выполнения GET запроса:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://yourserver.org/get", parameters: ["name": "user", "pass": "12345"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
     }
```

Более подробные примеры запросов приведены в [описании либы](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#usage).

Comment: Посмотрите на мой комментарий выше, то же самое спрашиваю и у Вас. Буду рад, если сможете прояснить ситуацию.